# Moq Setup IRepository<TEntity> (EF Core)

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, moq, xunit

I am using Moq and trying to setup the `GetPagedList` mock for `IRepository<TEntity>`

below is the interface i am trying to mock

IPagedList GetPagedList(Expression> predicate = null, Func, IOrderedQueryable> orderBy = null, Func, IIncludableQueryable> include = null, int pageIndex = 0, int pageSize = 20, bool = true);

My service

```
public class StudentService 
{
    private readonly IRepository<Student> _repo;          

    public StudentService( IUnitOfWork unitOfWork )
    {
        _repo = unitOfWork.GetRepository<Student>();             
        _unitOfWork = unitOfWork;          
    }

    public IPagedList<Student> Get(int id)
    {

     return _repo.GetPagedList(predicate: a => a.id == id);
    }
 }
```

My Unit Test

```
[Fact]
public void StudentService_GetStudentClasses_ReturnListOfClasses()
{
    int studentId = 100;

    _mockStudentRepo.Setup(x => x.GetPagedList(It.IsAny <
     Expression<Func<Student, bool>>,
    Func<IQueryable<Student>, IOrderedQueryable<Student>>,
     Func<IQueryable<Student>, IIncludableQueryable<Student, object>>,
     int, int, bool > ())).Returns(MockStudentList.Where(a => a.id == studentId ()).ToPagedList(0, 20));

}
```

Getting this error

> Using the generic method `It.IsAny<TValue>()` requires 1 type arguments.

Any ideas on how to fix this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Without a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that clarifies your specific problem or additional details to highlight exactly what was done, it will be difficult to reproduce the problem that would allow a better understanding of what is the *actual* problem.

Comment: BTW I just found it this morning, because of the optional argument I have to have an It.IsAny<> for each argument in the setup _mockStudentRepo.Setup(x => x.GetPagedList(
        It.IsAny<Expression<Func<Student, bool>>>(),
     It.IsAny<Func<IQueryable<Student>, IOrderedQueryable<Student>>>(),
     It.IsAny<Func<IQueryable<Student>, IIncludableQueryable<Student, object>>>(),
     It.IsAny<int>(), 
     It.IsAny<int>(),
     It.IsAny<bool>())).Returns(MockStudentList.Where(a => a.id == studentId ()).ToPagedList(0, 20)));

Comment: Yes that is a must.